# To draw random picture with OpenGL ES in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I need to set random picture (type noise pixel) necessarily with using **OpenGL** ES. Without openGL (in ios) we have did it like this:

```
 //declare variable:
  UIImage* myImage;
  UIImageView *imageView; 
  CGRect rect;   

//function whitch drawing random pixel-array picture and display it on screen     ios-device;
-(void)setPicture 
{
    if(imageView!=NULL)
    {
        //Addition removal imageView
        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
        imageView = NULL; //
    }
    int width = 352; //sizes 
    int height = 288;

    size_t bufferLength = width * height * 4; //
    uint8_t* pixels = (uint8_t*)malloc(bufferLength); //
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferLength/2; i++) {
        pixels[i] = rand() % 255; //obtain random pixel array
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * 4, space, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast); // 

    CGImageRef toCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx); 
    UIImage * uiimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:toCGImage]; //reflect pixel array to picture

    CGImageRelease(toCGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    free(pixels);

    myImage = uiimage;
    //

    rect = self.view.bounds; //

    if(imageView == NULL)
    {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        imageView.image = myImage;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        NSLog(@"NULL");
    } else
    {
        [imageView setNeedsDisplay];
        NSLog(@"Dewnull");
    }
}
```

Same picture displays on screen after calling of my function.

[image]

**Questions**

Is it possible to set similar picture on ios screen with **openGL ES**? How to make it? Will it work faster then my function?

Answer (score 0):

See the section ['Procedural Textures: “Random” Noise'](https://www.raywenderlich.com/70208/opengl-es-pixel-shaders-tutorial).  Is it faster? to generate, almost certainly yes, because the GPU can easily parallelize this process.  Reading back from the GPU can be slow though; I imagine maybe less so on iOS because the memory is unified.  Profile it and see.  It depends what you are doing with the texture.